# Linq to Entity get a Date from DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

var islemList = (from isl in entities.Islemler where (**isl.KayitTarihi.Date** >= dbas && isl.**KayitTarihi.Value.Date** <=  dbit) select isl);

It gives error: date is not supported in LINQ to Entities... 
How can i get date in linq.

Comment: What is the type of dbas and dbit? Is it DateTime?
And what is KayitTarihi.Value is it navigation property?

Comment: Try it without the `.Date` and `.Value.Date` if your dataType is DateTime (nullable).

Answer (score 30):

Use [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx).

Comment: Note that EntityFunctions is now deprecated and System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions should be used instead.

Comment: *Now* being EF 6 onwards. The implementations haven't changed, it's simply a rename with the old functions delegating to the new functions, so you can safely update your existing code. From the commit message: *"The classes with the old names basically just delegate to the new classes and are also marked as obsolete to help move people to the new classes."*

Comment: EntityFunctions.TruncateTime is now deprecated, instead use DbFunctions.TruncateTime

Answer (score 1):

if `KayitTarihi` is a date column in DB (and dbas and dbit are DateTime), use:

```
var islemList = (from isl in entities.Islemler where (isl.KayitTarihi >= dbas && isl.KayitTarihi <= dbit) select isl);
```

Comment: KayitTarihi is DateTime but i need just Date

Comment: Try `((Nullable<DateTime>)isl.KayitTarihi.Date)`. Not sure how si LINQ going to react.
You could alternatively modify `dbas` and `dbit` (if they are without the time part) so you do not have to extract Date value from `KayitTarihi`: `...where (isl.KayitTarihi >= dbas && isl.KayitTarihi < dbit.AddDays(1))...`.

Answer (score -2):

The .Date property is not supported in Linq to Entities (though it may be supported in other implementations of Linq).

I realize that you only want to compare the dates, but there is no real problem with comparing the datetimes if the dbas and dbit values are datetimes with time 00:00:00.
You might have to offset the dates or use other inequality checks to get the proper interval but the comparison will work as you intend.

I would personally go with Jandek's solution.